# Exclusive Lock Pipeline Level - Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Currently, our inhertited pipelines (not the best designed, but it's what I've got for now), look something like this:

`build -> provision + deploy (pipeline per env) -> acceptance test`

I only want to be able to do one deployment at a time, so I'm looking at Exclusive Locks.

Unfortunately, these seem to work at the step level, not the pipeline level. So given my provision + deploy pipeline contains multiple steps, how can I prevent step 1 from pipeline run 1 running then step 1 from pipeline 2 running etc?

I can't see a way to apply the exclusive lock at the pipeline level.

Our QA provision + deploy pipeline yml looks like this (before adding the locks):

```
pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"

resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: apiBuild
      source: "API/Build"
      trigger:
        enabled: true
        branches:
          include:
            - main

trigger: none
pr: none

variables:
  - template: _pipeline/variables/allVariables.yml
    parameters:
      deployEnvironment: Qa

stages:
  - stage: provisionInfrastructureTemplates
    displayName: Provision Templates infrastructure
    dependsOn: []
    jobs:
      - template: _pipeline/stages/jobs/provisionTemplates.yml

  - stage: templatesAcceptanceTests
    displayName: Templates acceptance tests
    dependsOn: provisionInfrastructureTemplates
    jobs:
      - template: _pipeline/stages/jobs/acceptanceTestsTemplates.yml

  - stage: provisionInfrastructureClients
    displayName: Provision Clients infrastructure
    dependsOn: []
    jobs:
      - template: _pipeline/stages/jobs/provisionClients.yml

  - stage: clientsAcceptanceTests
    displayName: Clients acceptance tests
    dependsOn: provisionInfrastructureClients
    jobs:
      - template: _pipeline/stages/jobs/acceptanceTestsClients.yml

  - stage: provisionInfrastructureReports
    displayName: Provision Reports infrastructure
    dependsOn: []
    jobs:
      - template: _pipeline/stages/jobs/provisionReports.yml

  - stage: reportsAcceptanceTests
    displayName: Reports acceptance tests
    dependsOn: provisionInfrastructureReports
    jobs:
      - template: _pipeline/stages/jobs/acceptanceTestsReports.yml
  
  - stage: upgradePreviewImage
    displayName: Upgrade preview image
    dependsOn: []
    jobs:
      - template: _pipeline/stages/jobs/upgradePreviewImage.yml
  
  - stage: provisionInfrastructureDocuments
    displayName: Provision Documents infrastructure
    dependsOn: upgradePreviewImage
    jobs:
      - template: _pipeline/stages/jobs/provisionDocuments.yml
        
  
  - stage: documentsAcceptanceTests
    displayName: Documents acceptance tests
    dependsOn: provisionInfrastructureDocuments
    jobs:
      - template: _pipeline/stages/jobs/acceptanceTestsDocuments.yml
        
  - stage: provisionInfrastructureNotifications
    displayName: Provision Notifications infrastructure
    dependsOn: []
    jobs:
      - template: _pipeline/stages/jobs/provisionNotifications.yml

  - stage: provisionEventGridSubscriptions
    displayName: Provision Event Grid Subscriptions
    dependsOn: [clientsAcceptanceTests, templatesAcceptanceTests, reportsAcceptanceTests, documentsAcceptanceTests, provisionInfrastructureNotifications]
    jobs:
      - template: _pipeline/stages/jobs/provisionEventGridSubscriptions.yml

  - stage: workflowTests
    displayName: Workflow tests
    dependsOn: provisionEventGridSubscriptions
    jobs:
      - template: _pipeline/stages/jobs/workflowTests.yml
```

As an aside, I know our services ought to be independently deployable, they're not currently, that's part of the tech debt we're dealing with so, as things stand, they need deploying together.

Answer (score 1):

When you put the jobs in separate stages. The exclusive lock of the environment will be judged separately.

It is not able to apply the exclusive lock at the pipeline level.

To meet your requirement, you can define required the jobs in the same stage.  The  Exclusive Lock will be judged before running.

When set the environments exclusive lock in the same stage, all environments referenced in a stage will be locked. Only when the current Pipeline Run Stage finished, the next Pipeline run will continue to run.

Here is an example:

```
stages:
- stage: Test
  displayName: Test
  lockBehavior: sequential

  jobs:
  - deployment: Test1
    displayName: 'Test'
    environment: Test2
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script:  echo "Test"

  - deployment: Test
    displayName: 'Test2'
    environment: Test2
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - script: echo "Test"
```

Comment: Is this still true, the docs state that you can do an exclusive lock at the pipeline level